# Why is this central area of the STL being filled in?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, stl, python

We've been doing some work automatically generating STL files using Python.  We've made a ring of cubes like so:

[image: Python generated ring of cubes]

Importing it into Cura still makes it look valid, with a hole in the center:

[image: Ring of cubes in Cura]

However, post slicing it comes up with saying it will take 14 hours to print!  A ludicrous time.  Looking at the preview, it seems to be adding supports to the entire inside of the structure:

[image: Slicing preview]

And also a top / bottom layer:

[image: Slicing preview - top]

[image: Slicing preview - bottom]

Why is this?  You can tell it's adding supports to the center and is not filled in due to the differing structure midway through the block:

[image: Close up of support structures midway]

Comment: This is a broken STL file see e.g. [this answer](/a/639/), probably due to incorrect normals or hidden faces, this has been asked before. A very good answer to question *"[Cura messes up my print. How can I make it print what I see in Blender?](/q/15868)"* is found [here](/a/15881/). The question is very good though, nice images, maybe this question deserves an answer to be referenced later, this has no link to Blender, but does hint to a broken STL file.

Comment: Usually hidden faces have caused that kind of problem for me.  It looks like you already have an unwanted surface in the hole after the import.

Comment: +1 Nice question and nice images. However, @0scar - should this be closed as a duplicate? If so, against which of the two previous questions..?

Comment: I hoped @Trish would notice this question, as this is Trishes specialty, with many excellent answers on this subject.

Comment: I'm new to this forum, but am quite experienced in generating 3d models. Can you share the STL that is causing the problem? I suspect you have concave surfaces that aren't triangulating as expected. Have you tried opening your STL in Blender and running the 3D print tests that software provides?

Comment: Any suggestions for a site I can upload the STL file to?  I'm happy to, it's just a square so it's not private. @RonJensen

Comment: Found out you can upload it to GitHub, so here's the code that generates it and the STL file. The GitHub rendering of the STL file seems wrong.  Blender, Cura and MatPlotLib all seem to display it accurately. https://gist.github.com/popey456963/470d995032d321b6e49100c51d65f249

Comment: Your normals are flipped randomly. When you generate the vertices of the triangles you need to keep the winding order consistent. This is important to Cura so it knows what the "inside" and "outside" of the model is.

Comment: It looks to be a straightforward item - would you like it remade ?   (assuming this is still of use a year later)

Answer (score 3):

The surfaces are clearly ill defined - it shows the top surface as a bottom one (those are marked red), and so the normals of that surface are pointing to the wrong direction.